# mysql current time with 0 seconds

Tags: mysql

I want to insert/update data into a table with the current time, but I want the seconds to be 0, for example, '2014-06-27 23:36:**00**'. How do I achieve this?

I think MAKETIME() could somehow be involved, but I really have no idea how.

`CURDATE() + INTERVAL HOUR() HOUR + INTERVAL MINUTE() MINUTE` unfortunately doesn't work, which is not surprising.

Edit: final solution - `DATE_FORMAT(CURTIME(), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:00')`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
mysql> select date_format(current_timestamp(), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:00') as ts_zero_seconds;
+---------------------+
| ts_zero_seconds     |
+---------------------+
| 2014-06-27 02:06:00 |
+---------------------+
```

Comment: That should be `%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:00`. I don't do 12 hours.

Answer (score 2):

Your idea should work with arguments to the functions:

```
CURDATE() + INTERVAL HOUR(now()) HOUR + INTERVAL MINUTE(now()) MINUTE
```

Comment: Well, as ridiculous as it is, it works, thanks. I will probably take @Bill Karwin's solution though, it's much shorter if I replace `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()` with `CURTIME()`, it works, and I only need it very rarely.

Comment: As a note, Bill's solution returns a string.  This solution returns a datetime, which seemed to be what the question was asking for.

Comment: It's for insertion into database in a datetime column. It accepts strings.

Answer (score 2):

I know that there is already an accepted answer and I'm a bit late to the conversation, but just putting in my 2 cents for anyone it may help. This is what I use to get a timestamp with 0 seconds. Feel free to point out any flaws in my logic. =)

`select CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - interval second(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) second`

Simply take the timestamp and subtract the seconds from it. This also works for datetime or timestamp columns in tables. So, if you'd like to select a timestamp column with 0 seconds, use this:

`select timestamp_col - interval second(timestamp_col) second from table`